# inflate xml in sliding drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Hi I have created a sliding drawer and have created an scrollable xml file which I would like to inflate when user taps a button within the sliding drawer.  However when the button has been tapped nothing displays apart from a blank screen.  Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong?
 here is my code:
 xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/text2" />

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/image"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:text="@string/text1" />

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and java:

```
next3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity, null);
        slider.animateClose();


    }
});
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity, null);
```

Creates (inflates) the content of your layout file, but you haven't put the returned View anywhere.

Do you want to put the ScrollView inside the sliding drawer? If so, change to:

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity, slider);
```